# Cloning HTMLElements with jQuery fails strangely

Tags: jquery, events, clone

I'm having a problem with jQuery and `.clone(true, true)`. Take a look **[on this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RPAS/1/)**.

The problem is: when I clone an object (using `.clone(true, true)` -- deep: data and events), the events works, but apply all functions on the original object (the model object).

All will be clear on read the code.

Bye and thanks for any help :)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is your extensive use of `exampleVariable = $(this)`.

When you use the variable instead of explicitly using `$(this)`, you're not using the current `$(this)` if that makes any sense.

I've made some changes: (fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PGM6W/)

```
        // On click on more, append a new model
        // Will update table buttons too
        // THIS WORKS FINE, except if I click on remove and click on this two times (try it)
        selfRow.find('a.more').click(function(){
            $(this).parents("table").append(model.clone(true, true));
            updateModel(selfTable);
        });

        // On click on remove, will remove current row
        // Will update table buttons too
        // THIS NOT WORKS FINE, and broke the a.more event!
        selfRow.find('a.remove').click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
            updateModel(selfTable);
        });
```

Comment: Great! I do some modifications to work even better, but you are totally right. Thanks for help. [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/PGM6W/2/).